# Cannot Open firefox on rsDriver on RSelenium Mac

Tags: r, selenium, firefox, rselenium

I have a problem oppenning firefox with RSelenium on R on my mac.

When I put:

```
remDr <- rsDriver(browser = "firefox", port=4443L)$client
```

I get this answer

```
checking Selenium Server versions:
BEGIN: PREDOWNLOAD
BEGIN: DOWNLOAD
BEGIN: POSTDOWNLOAD
checking chromedriver versions:
BEGIN: PREDOWNLOAD
BEGIN: DOWNLOAD
BEGIN: POSTDOWNLOAD
checking geckodriver versions:
BEGIN: PREDOWNLOAD
BEGIN: DOWNLOAD
BEGIN: POSTDOWNLOAD
checking phantomjs versions:
BEGIN: PREDOWNLOAD
BEGIN: DOWNLOAD
BEGIN: POSTDOWNLOAD
[1] "Connecting to remote server"
Could not open firefox browser.
Client error message:
Undefined error in httr call. httr output: Failed to connect to localhost port 4443: Connection refused
Check server log for further details.
Warning message:
In rsDriver(browser = "firefox", port = 4443L) :
  Could not determine server status.
```

Firefox page does not open.

Is there anyone knowing what might be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

For everyone who might be in a similar situation, I finally managed to solve this issue by installing [Java SE Development Kit 14](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase-downloads.html) on my Mac.

I did not close the post because I thought it might help someone else.

Comment: Hey, Leo! Could you tell more about your solution, please? You installed Java SE DK and?

Comment: Sorry for the late answer, I rerun RSelenium and it worked. From what I learnt these past few months using RSelenium, it's working way better on firefox than chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Above didn't work for me and this problem drove me crazy for 2 days :( Here's finally what worked for me:

1. Make sure you install the above Java Development kit and the Firefox browser
2. Install geckodriver as described here: https://medium.com/dropout-analytics/selenium-and-geckodriver-on-mac-b411dbfe61bc
3. In R, uninstall RSelenium. Make sure to install the following packages in exactly this order:
4. netstat
5. wdman
6. rvest
7. If you're not sure you installed in the correct order, re-install all of them in order. It will save your sanity
8. Only then (!!) install RSelenium
9. Follow the remainder in this guide: https://rpubs.com/grahamplace/rseleniumonmac
10. When prompted in above guide to install the standalone Selenium, go to http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/index.html
11. Send me a donation equal to the amount you would pay a shrink for 2 days worth of therapy. Just kidding.

After this, you should be set.

Comment: RSelenium is a required package for wdman?

Comment: Yeah somehow it needed it under the hood, at that point I stopped questioning requirements and just tried to make it work lol hope the steps are helpful