# Why can't I establish the connection?

Tags: r, rselenium

I am trying to **scrape** some comments from a job feedback web site using `RSelenium`.

I am facing a following problem when I try to run this line of code:

```
library(RSelenium)
rs <- rsDriver(browser = "firefox", check = FALSE)
```

And then the problem pops up:

```
  [1] "Connecting to remote server"
    Could not open firefox browser.
    Client error message:
    Undefined error in httr call. httr output: Failed to connect to localhost port 4567: Connection refused
    Check server log for further details.
    Warning:
    В rsDriver(browser = "firefox", check = FALSE) :
      Could not determine server status.
```

The latest Java and Mozilla Firefox versions are installed onto my laptop. Also added the path to Java's bin in the Win system options. I have no clue why this problem occurs.

Comment: I see that one guy helped himself by installing Java SDK but he has MacOS. Might be the solution for Mac users. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67804907/cannot-open-firefox-on-rsdriver-on-rselenium-mac

Comment: try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42252080/rselenium-couldnt-connect-to-host-rsdriver https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45395849/cant-execute-rsdriver-connection-refused